# Is a link-only answer acceptable if a Stack Exchange sister site Q/A offers many solutions to a question?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, link-only-answers, cross-posting

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10544688/30225

I answered this question a long time ago pointing to an answer on SuperUser. I felt that that q/a offered many solutions and perhaps a link to the QA is better than me copying each answer?

What's the best solution in this case - noting that the answer was created many years ago and that rules/processes are now likely different?

Comment: I don't see why this is a dup? The one it's marked as dupe to doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 18):

> it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and
>   provide the link for reference.

The auto-comment sums it up pretty well...

In general, you can quote or paraphrase source material so long as you provide proper attribution.

In this specific case; I would probably grab the snippet from the highest voted answer, give attribution to the author and add the link for additional reading.

The fact that the source is also inside the SE network is, more or less, irrelevant. Treat it like any other offsite resource.

Comment: This is the problem. What if there many answers there? Duplicating the answers doesn't seem right in this case?

Comment: @PreetSangha: Than you decide which parts of which ones are best / most important, and quote/paraphrase only those.

Comment: @PreetSangha Choose the top few, or the ones you think are most helpful and mention that there are more in the link description.

Comment: @apaul34208 - ok - perhaps that's correct for this one. But what about in the general case where there are many answers all equally valid?

Comment: @PreetSangha if there are many answers, all equally valid, then the question is likely a little too broad.

Comment: If there are more answers to the same or a similar question on another SE site, surely that indicates that it's off-topic here, no?

Comment: @RogerRowland no - the topic areas of some SE sites overlap, and it's been explicitly pointed out before that on-topicness on one site is not sufficient to indicate off-topicness on all others.

Comment: @MarkAmery Fair point and probably not a can of worms to be opened up again here ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If the only duplicate you can find is on another site, that's a great resource to refer to for further reading.

Still, your answer should be a good, properly attributed complete and self-contained answer.

As an example, an answer I posted on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) referring to [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/):
[Why do some websites have ?utf8=[check mark] in their title?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27338181).

---

If you are inclined to maintain your old post, there's nothing stopping you from upgrading it to be a good answer under our current norms.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the real question is "How do I pick a snippet if the whole page is good?"

The reason for snippets is that the Internet is a dynamic place (and SE sites moreso than the rest of the Internet). You never know when a resource will go away (hang around Meta enough and you'll see old off-topic questions you might have considered useful get deleted). So when picking a snippet or quote, you should ask yourself one question

> If this page were deleted tomorrow, what would be the most helpful thing I could copy now to ensure people are still helped by this page in the future?

If you can answer that you'll have some excellent answers here.